# Swift Building IP 4 address class for a iOS project

Tags: swift, string, parsing, int, ip-address

I was trying to create my own class for IP Address. I want to use this for a iOS project. I'm trying to figure out were to put the code to put the range between 0 to 255. The separator isn't working correctly. I want it to hold a ip address like 192.168.0.1 if I enter 400.168.0.1 it should return a error or say please type a real ip address as one of the output that that something wrong. I trying to create a class that when you input a ip address it should hold in the class itself. I want make a iOS app later on that will help people figure how to distribute IP address for cisco routers and switches. basically want to make a app that helps people with CIDR ip address notations like this webpage program that I found online, but I can barely use without internet connection. http://jodies.de/ipcalc  if I could program a mobile application that can do what this website would be great for my line of work in networking.

```
import UIKit

class IP4 {
    var ipA: Int?
    var ipB: Int?
    var ipC: Int?
    var ipD: Int?

    func fullIP() -> Int {
        var parts: [Int] = []

        if let ipA = self.ipA {
            parts += [ipA]
        }

        if let ipB = self.ipB {
            parts += [ipB]
        }

        if let ipC = self.ipC {
            parts += [ipC]
        }

        if let ipD = self.ipD {
            parts += [ipD]
        }
        return parts.joined(separator: ".")
    }
}

let ipaddress = IP4()
ipaddress.ipA = 223
ipaddress.ipB = 9
ipaddress.ipC = 50
ipaddress.ipD = 60
```

Comment: *Hint:* At some point you have to convert the integers to strings ...

Comment: Why are `ipA`-`ipD` optional? According to the specification all 4 parts are required.

Comment: What type of result do you want to make? String representation? (As your `"."` is suggesting.) Network order byte sequence? (Then the result type should be an ordered collection like `Data` or `[UInt8]`.) Or host order internal representation? (`UInt32` is preferred in this case.) It is not clear enough what you are trying to generate.

Comment: I want it to hold a ip address like 192.168.0.1   if I enter 400.168.0.1 it should return a error or say please type a real ip address.

Comment: Then your `fullIP()` method is not needed, if you say just to hold. What's the purpose of the method?

Comment: this method is taking the 4 numbers and creating a full ip address by adding "." or combine the four numbers that's given into a real ip address number.

Comment: I have explained already, there are many types of _a real ip address number_. What type do you want?

Comment: I want to apply the rule that 255.255.255.255 is the max range for a ip address and other rules like CIDR ip address notation will be also added. Class A to D ip address by range.

Comment: Why don't you directly answer my question? Which type of output do you want with `fullIP()`?

Comment: 233.9.50.60 or this not right ip address. it's supposed to add all the parts together to make a ip address with string dots. I can scrap the whole method and build something else. The whole point is that this class accept a ip address string and does a check to see if the numbers in each 8 bit hasn't reach over 255.

Comment: Then you do not need `fullIP()`.

Comment: And the functionality _The whole point is that this class accept a ip address string and does a check to see if the numbers in each 8 bit hasn't reach over 255._ is in my answer. Remove all description of ClassA something (readers already know or can easily find it on the web), and include the functionality you want in the text of your question.

Comment: Yeah, I remove the extra class A,B,C,D from the question. I'll work on testing the new basic ip address class that you created from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example, which can be tested on the Playground. (Tested on Xcode 9.4.1.)

```
import Foundation

struct IPv4: CustomStringConvertible, Equatable, Hashable {

    enum Errors: Error {
        case invalidFormat
        case octetOutOfRange
    }

    var ipA: UInt8
    var ipB: UInt8
    var ipC: UInt8
    var ipD: UInt8

    init() {
        ipA = 0
        ipB = 0
        ipC = 0
        ipD = 0
    }

    init(_ ipA: UInt8, _ ipB: UInt8, _ ipC: UInt8, _ ipD: UInt8) {
        self.ipA = ipA
        self.ipB = ipB
        self.ipC = ipC
        self.ipD = ipD
    }

    private static let parsingRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^([0-9]{1,3})\\.([0-9]{1,3})\\.([0-9]{1,3})\\.([0-9]{1,3})$")
    init(_ ipString: String) throws {
        guard let match = IPv4.parsingRegex.firstMatch(in: ipString, range: NSRange(0..<ipString.utf16.count)) else {
            throw Errors.invalidFormat
        }
        let strA = ipString[Range(match.range(at: 1), in: ipString)!]
        let strB = ipString[Range(match.range(at: 2), in: ipString)!]
        let strC = ipString[Range(match.range(at: 3), in: ipString)!]
        let strD = ipString[Range(match.range(at: 4), in: ipString)!]
        guard
            let ipA = UInt8(strA),
            let ipB = UInt8(strB),
            let ipC = UInt8(strC),
            let ipD = UInt8(strD)
        else {throw Errors.octetOutOfRange}
        self.ipA = ipA
        self.ipB = ipB
        self.ipC = ipC
        self.ipD = ipD
    }

    var description: String {
        return "\(ipA).\(ipB).\(ipC).\(ipD)"
    }

    var networkBytes: Data {
        return Data(bytes: [ipA, ipB, ipC, ipD])
    }

    var hostWord: UInt32 {
        return UInt32(ipA) << 24 + UInt32(ipB) << 16 + UInt32(ipC) << 8 + UInt32(ipD)
    }
}

let ip = IPv4(223, 9, 50, 60)
print(ip) //->223.9.50.60

do {
    let ip = try IPv4("400.168.0.1")
    print(ip)
} catch {
    print(error) //->octetOutOfRange
}
```

- Better use `struct` than `class`. As its equality should be judged by its contents, not by its address in the heap.
- IPv4 address is made of 4 octets. You should better use `UInt8`, non-Optional. No parts can be nil.
- There's no numeric type which can hold 3-decimal points. If you want to generate a notation like `192.168.0.1`, it needs to be a `String`.

I have prepared 3 types of outputs. Think carefully which one you want.

Also find which part of my code is implementing *if I enter 400.168.0.1 it should return a error*.

---

I show you some extensions for my `struct`, which may be some help to make similar functionalities shown in the linked site.

To make binary representation:

```
extension UInt8 {
    var fixedBinaryDescription: String {
        let binStr = String(self, radix: 2)
        return String(repeating: "0", count: 8-binStr.count) + binStr
    }
}

extension IPv4 {
    var binaryDescription: String {
        return "\(ipA.fixedBinaryDescription).\(ipB.fixedBinaryDescription).\(ipC.fixedBinaryDescription).\(ipD.fixedBinaryDescription)"
    }
}
print(ip.binaryDescription) //->11011111.00001001.00110010.00111100
```

To work with masks:

```
extension IPv4 {
    init(maskOfLength len: Int) {
        let highBits: [UInt8] = [
            0b10000000,
            0b11000000,
            0b11100000,
            0b11110000,
            0b11111000,
            0b11111100,
            0b11111110,
            0b11111111,
        ]
        switch len {
        case 0:
            self = IPv4(0, 0, 0, 0)
        case 1...8:
            self = IPv4(highBits[len-1], 0, 0, 0)
        case 9...16:
            self = IPv4(0b11111111, highBits[len-9], 0, 0)
        case 17...24:
            self = IPv4(0b11111111, 0b11111111, highBits[len-17], 0)
        case 25...32:
            self = IPv4(0b11111111, 0b11111111, 0b11111111, highBits[len-25])
        default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }

    func masked(by mask: IPv4) -> IPv4 {
        return IPv4(self.ipA & mask.ipA, self.ipB & mask.ipB, self.ipC & mask.ipC, self.ipD & mask.ipD)
    }
}

let mask = IPv4(maskOfLength: 24)
print(mask.binaryDescription) //->11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000
print(ip.masked(by: mask).binaryDescription) //->11011111.00001001.00110010.00000000
```

---

An extension to get address class of IP v4.

```
enum IPv4AddressClass {
    case a
    case b
    case c
    case d
    case e
}
extension IPv4 {
    var addressClass: IPv4AddressClass {
        if ipA & 0b1_0000000 == 0b0_0000000 {
            return .a
        } else if ipA & 0b11_000000 == 0b10_000000 {
            return .b
        } else if ipA & 0b111_00000 == 0b110_00000 {
            return .c
        } else if ipA & 0b1111_0000 == 0b1110_0000 {
            return .d
        } else {
            return .e
        }
    }
}
print(ip.addressClass) //->c
```

Comment: I'm amazed at what you can program in swift. I look into using the data type UInt8. I mainly use string and int. I never really work with these other types of data types before.

Comment: When you work with networking or hardware specific features (for example Bluetooth devices), you may need it. I hope my code can help you make great apps. And please remember, showing your own code would be great help to write answers, but when lacking enough explanation of what you really want to do, the code may mislead the readers.

Comment: It looks like your code form the class A, B, C, D, E of a ip address or more of a range. Maybe it's better do this in an if condition instead of a case. I'm sure someone would find your case switch useful. in developing  a app for ip address distribution for Cisco routers and switches.

Comment: Added another extension to get address class. In fact, people usually use 32-bit data type (`UInt32` in Swift) to represent IP v4 address, when each octet needed, they split it into 4 octets. And 32-bit data (as well as 4-octet data) can represent whole IP v4 addresses including Class E.

Comment: I looked up unint4 and swift does have this data type in there frame work. I'll probably follow your advice using 4 bit data type and UInt32 data type to hold the ip address bit.

Comment: Good luck. And if you find some difficulty using `UInt32`, better start a new thread. There are many readers who can help you, just try to explain carefully what you want to do.

Comment: Hi guys! ,
@OOPer , can you please elaborate on the mask validation?
i  wanna  validate it with an ip but it seems the there is a luck of information regarding the particularly with iOS

Comment: @ironRoei, I'm sorry but I do now understand what you mean with _mask validation_ . Better start a new thread of your own and try to explain what you want to do as specific as possible. Good luck.